# Mobile app API scaling strategy

Tags: java, mysql, jetty, netty, quasar

Our API was developed for supporting a million users. Since we have reached half a million mark within 4 months we are now in the process of scaling it to support 10 Million users which we plan to reach in a year. The targets are realistic because we are now shipping our core data processing/aggregation logic as an SDK to other apps.

The current API is HTTP post in which the body is a JSON. When a new user registers he uploads roughly 200KB of data from the device. Previously we used to process the data server side but now we are processing it on device itself.

Thereafter the app will upload around 2KB of data per day and download about the same. For users with multiple mobile devices the numbers are a bit more but that is only 1% of the total user base.

Right now our API servers use Jetty+Jersey with an average of around 200 concurrent connections. It can handle around 500-1000 concurrent connections (depending on the type of request).

Each API server(Total 4) has 120 Database connections. Our workload is 80% Write and 20% Read with negligible updates.

Right now the API is synchronous by which i mean that for every request we store/retrieve data and send back the ack/data to the client.

One way to scale would be to scale(vertically and/or horizontally) our API servers and shard the database on userId. Sharding of database is done because our estimates show that we need 1TB of data storage per million users. We also plan to migrate to SSDs, but it will take some time as we have our own datacenter and migration is in process.

The main challenge I foresee is handling burst of new users as the sdk rolls out into a popular app. There are some approaches i am considering:

1) During write requests just extract the entities, push to KAFKA and send an ACK to the client. Consumers than extract entities to persist from the queue and insert them in batches.

2) Use different servers of read and write. For read use the existing synchronous architecture. For write requests expose a different URL backed by Netty which will extract the entities to persist and push them on to an in-memory queue, send ACK to client. Asynchronously transfer to kafka queue and than finally to database.

3) Use asynchronous server Quasar+Comsat and Lightweight threads for every request and let the client wait for acks(get the autoincrement ids for persisted entites as well). The problem is that num of DB connections is the bottleneck, allowing many concurrent light weight threads to spawn may not really help.

Any help on pointing out pros/cons/improvements to these approaches or suggestion for a new approach will be of great help. Perspective on which of these approaches would stand true even if we scale from 10M to 100M would also help. We do not a have a web interface so all the data transfer is purely json, being in developing nation we also have to support devices on 2G and lots of network disconnections so this also has to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice**: I'm part of the Quasar/Comsat team.

I don't see these approaches as mutually exclusive, I only advice against using async APIs pervasively as they'll compromise the readability/maintainability (so, the future) of your code base, and that's where Quasar/Comsat can help a lot with their sync APIs (but fiber- rather than thread-blocking, so as efficient as async).

If you care a lot about durability then I'd also keep data only in volatile memory for as little as possible. I'm not a Kafka expert but I think it can handle a lot of load and there's a [Comsat integration in 0.6.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/puniverse/comsat/blob/master/comsat-kafka/src/main/java/co/paralleluniverse/fibers/kafka/FiberKafkaProducer.java).

Yes, firing up a lot of fibers all waiting on DB pools will not help your throughput. Either you need some Kafka (or similar) + async transfer amortizing layer or a faster DB.

Keep in mind that since fibers are very cheap you can keep them blocked and allow a sync model (and a sync response) to clients even if there are a lot of them, provided you use Quasar-integrated APIs (or write your own, [which is not difficult at all](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2014/08/12/noasync/)).

Finally I'm not sure if your API is monolithic or microservices, especially in the latter case you might be interested in [this post of ours about Comsat VS. regular HTTP client performance](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2015/12/02/http-clients/).

Comment: Is there an embedded jetty + jersey integration?

Comment: [Yes for Jersey](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/comsat/#rest-services) and [yes for Jetty](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/comsat/#enabling-comsat).

Comment: Yes, Comsat and Quasar are production-ready. See f.e. [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/quasar-pulsar-user/production/quasar-pulsar-user/lJcNtQp0Vr4/TnXRxXq53C0J) and [JBender](https://github.com/pinterest/jbender).